# Different results depending on the location of predictor in OLS

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, least-squares

In the code below, I found that the coefficients comes out differently depending on the position of a.I tried the same using ols in Python, and the same result came out.
What's wrong with this?? I have to put in a, so please help me...

```
set.seed(0)

x1 <- rtruncnorm(20, -10, 10)

x2 <- rtruncnorm(20, -10, 10)

a <- rep(c(0,1), 10)

y <- a

fit <- lm(y~ x1 + x2 + a + a:x1 + a:x2);coef(fit)

fit2 <- lm(y~a + x1 + x2 + a:x1 + a:x2);coef(fit2)
```

this is coefficients.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `y` as being equal to `a` with the expression `y <- a`.

You are regressing `y` on `a`.  Therefore the coefficient of `a` should be `1`, and the coefficient of everything else should be `0`.

This is the output that you are seeing in both your regressions. It's just that because of floating point math, you are not seeing `0` exactly but numbers like `9.032116e-17`, which are basically `0`.

To get a sense of this visually you can plot the coefficients and see that in both cases the slope of `a` is `1` and everything else is `0`:

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(coef(fit),xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=seq_along(coef(fit)),labels=names(coef(fit)))

plot(coef(fit2),xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=seq_along(coef(fit2)),labels=names(coef(fit2)))
```

[image]

For more information about floating point errors in R, read [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (pdf).